# bash скрипт для поиска нужных строк в txt и сохранение их

Tags: bash, bat

Есть варианты переписать такой батник под bash? Есть огромный txt файл весом 100 гб, нужно быстро из него по списку определенных доменов, вытащить нужные почты.

```
@echo off
: start
SET base="C:\base.txt"
call :domain set domain

cls & echo Sorting Other...
FINDSTR /L /I /P /OFF /V "%domain%" %base% >> %base%-Other.txt

cls & echo Sorting USA...
FINDSTR /L /I /P /OFF "%domain%" %base% >> %base%-USA.txt

cls & echo end!
goto 
start

:domain
SET domain=@aim.com @xerox.com @dallas.net  @comcast.net @verizon.net @att.net @flash.net @wans.net @sbcglobal.net @charter.net @aol.com @love.com @ygm.com @games.com @wow.com @bellsouth.net @icloud.com @live.com @mac.com @me.com @netscape.net @mail.com @cox.net @rocketmail.com @ymail.com @earthlink.net @skyline.org @embarqmail.com @lineone.net @sccoast.net @skybest.com @torchlake.com @suddenlink.net @frontier.com @centurylink.net @snet.net @email.com @wowway.com @netzero.net @zoominternet.net @rcn.com @frontiernet.net @myfairpoint.net @atlanticbb.net @pldi.net @hughes.net @peoplepc.com @buckeye-express.com @wavecable.com @ix.netcom.com @ameritech.net @lycos.com @pacbell.net @cebridge.net @ptd.net @usa.com @hargray.com @fuse.net @knology.net @bresnan.net @gvtc.com @insightbb.com @surewest.net @optonline.net @twc.com @roadrunner.com @rr.com @adelphia.net @attbi.com @swbell.net @prodigy.net @nvbell.net @optimum.net @netscape.com @mypacks.net @mycompany.com @wmconnect.com @mchsi.com @ntlworld.com @aol.com @comcast.net @cox.net @att.net @charter.net @bellsouth.net @rcn.com @verizon.net @ntlworld.com @prodigy.net @ymail.com @aim.com @zoominternet.net @windstream.net @surewest.net @hawaiiantel.net @embarqmail.com @roadrunner.com @guerrillamailblock.com  @ameritech.net @telus.net @msn.com @juno.com @outlook.com @hotmail.com  @kiski.org @onsrud.com @ccpsnet.net @dallasr1.k12.mo.us @greenwichschools.org @eot.com @arvig.com @logical.net @rochester.rr @giains.com @vintagestock.com @dfas @us.army.mil @nasa.gov @hudson.us @yahoo.com.us @bloemen.us @jefferson.edu @browardschools.com @nass.usda.gov @fs.fed.us @seinet.us @wellesley @jefferson.kyschools.us .us
```

Comment: Вариантов масса! Покажите, что вы уже сделали, что не получается?

Comment: Пока что сделал это на Windows. Хотел узнать, какими средствами, это возможно реализовать на Linux? Уверен, что можно и на bash.

Comment: `man grep` очевидно.

Comment: Т.е. получается, я могу использовать что-то вроде этого?
`grep -E "(domain1.com|domain2.com |domain3.com)" test.txt`

Comment: Именно так, и не забудьте добавить регистронезависимость через `-i`. Если под условие подпадает немного, вначале грепаем в один файл общей регуляркой, затем из файла раскидываем по доменам, так будет имхо мыстрее, чем по 100 Гб регуляркой под каждый домен проходить